# Get Battery Info without WMI

Tags: c#, power-management

Is there some way to obtain the battery DesignCapacity and FullChargeCpacity without WMI ?
This values are not supported in WMI so I need to find other way to get them.

Or maybe somebody have better (easier) idea to get the wear level of battery in C#?

BTW
I try to use it this way but just returned null

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT DesignCapacity FROM Win32_Battery");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in query.Get())
{
    string dc = Convert.ToString(queryObj.GetPropertyValue("DesignCapacity"));
    label1.Text = dc + " mAh";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Download WMI Explorer to run and test WMI queries so that you know the information is available: http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm

Comment: The point of WMI is so you don't have to talk to the BIOS yourself.  Something you do *not* want to do.  Having unimplemented WMI properties and methods is not uncommon, you have to obtain an updated WMI provider from the machine manufacturer.  If available, it commonly isn't.

Comment: So there is no other way to get this data? If the WMI doesn't support this properties and machine manufacturer doesn't provide any WMI updates so whats the other way to get such data?

Comment: I wonder how the windows batter status works (the thing in the status tray). Does it not use WMI? If not, what does it use? (It doesn't "talk to the BIO" either.) And if it does use WMI, why can it not be replicated?

Comment: I already find one thing that can solve my every problems/questions
http://www.cpuid-pro.com/index.php
But the pricing convince me to search again :)
So the problem still exist how to obtain this values from system??

Answer (score 3):

To get those particular values you need to do separate queries against different classes instead of win32_battery.

`DesignCapacity` can be queried from BatteryStaticData

`FullChargeCacity` can be queried from BatteryFullChargedCapacity

You'll need to use a different scope in the code also for the query. These classes are found in `root/WMI` instead of `root/cimv2`

```
string scope = "root/WMI";
string query = "SELECT DesignedCapacity FROM BatteryStaticData";

ManagementObjectSearcher batteriesQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection batteries = batteriesQuery.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject battery in batteries)
{
    if (battery != null)
    {
        foreach (var property in battery.Properties)
        {
            Console.Log("Property name: " + property.Name + " Property value: " + property.Value);
        }
    }
}
```