# Trying to access battery level, c#

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to create an app for windows 8 using c# to display my current battery level.  I'm trying to query the win32_battery class for its relevant properties,but I'm getting an unusual result.  Here's my code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Battery");
    ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
    {
        txtBox.AppendText(obj.ToString() + "\r\n");
    };
}
```

My only result in the txtBox is

```
\\MIKESLAPTOP\root\cimv2:Win32_Battery.DeviceID=" ASUSTeKX401-44"
```

Any ideas why I am only reading theDevideID property?  All guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716559/get-battery-info-without-wmi

Comment: What does it display when you try that command `Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery` in a PowerShell console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected output.  You forgot to enumerate the properties of the query.  Make it look similar to this:

```
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) {
        foreach (var prop in obj.Properties) {
            if (prop.Value != null) {
                txtBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value));
            }
        }
    }
```